# How to get bundle product price tax for bundled product?

Tags: magento, bundle

Ok so I've got the max price for a bundled product using the code below in my list.phtml template, but the tax is not added, could someone shed some light on this please?

```
<?php

// Get product
$_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$_product->load($product_id);

echo Mage::helper('core')->currency(Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getMaxPrice(), true));

?>
```

Ideally I would like to get getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?> to display the price but this returns the base price which is zero. Any changes I make to the price.phtml file don't seem to have any effect either, would this suggest there is a plugin which is overriding it?

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you running? There's an old bundled/grouped product defect that you might have hit.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/224677/

Products are indexed with no tax so you have to add the tax yourself, but if you change your price.phtml with no effect you either have a cache running or a layer that overrides your class file.